# How to check apple watch mute status?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos-4

I am working on application where **i need to check apple watch mute button is On or off.**

In iPhone we can detect it using `AudioToolbox` framework **but in `watch OS` there is no framework with name `AudioToolbox`.**

So my question is how could we detect apple watch mute button is On or off .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching around i concluded that currently there is no way to check apple watch mute status.

Comment: really really?!

Comment: Yes ,according to my search this is not possible at least at this time.